# Why is Tomcat setting two JSESSIONID cookies?

Tags: tomcat7

I have a tomcat 7 instance which was installed and configured by another person.

I can see that it sets two JSESSIONID cookies for each request.

- One like

  ```
  JSESSIONID = {some hash}.{hostname_ajp port}
  ```
- Another one like

  ```
  JSESSIONID.some_chars = {other hash}
  ```

Expected behavior to have JSESSIONID only.
Reason couldn't be in deployed application because in my local Tomcat it runs as expected.

Could anyone give a tip about what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml` file and search for something like:

```
<Context path="/someContextDir" ... sessionCookieName="JSESSIONID">
```

Alternatively it can be in web.xml like this:

```
<cookie-config><name>JSESSIONID</name></cookie-config>
```